How to get entity from JPA?
I want to get entity with fields like
"id":[1],
"text":[some text]

to be able to manipulate them, but i get link to entity that look like
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository@b1e8d6a
With this
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Long> {


    @Query(value = "SELECT new io.stepa.StepaDomashniyBot.model.Question(QT.id, QT.text) FROM questionTable as QT WHERE id = 1", nativeQuery = true)
    Question getFirstQuestion();
    
}

My entity:
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "questionTable")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "text", nullable = false, length = 1000)
    private String text;


How can i get entity?
I tried:
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Long> {


    @Query(value = "SELECT new io.stepa.StepaDomashniyBot.model.Question(QT.id, QT.text) FROM questionTable as QT WHERE id = 1", nativeQuery = true)
    Question getFirstQuestion();

}

Expecting:
"id":[1],
"text":[some text]


The id is usually the primaryKey, so you can use the build in method findById(1L) instead your custom method getFirstQuestion()

Your question is a clasical use of JPA and not any corner-case scenario. So, any user guide that explains the JPA use will give you the correct explanation with examples. the most simple google search would give plenty of references to good user guides. Here is one that gives you an example that is exactly your use-case: Accessing Data with JPA
